# executing mdx within and sql query on a local cube

Tags: sql, mdx, openquery, localserver

I am trying to get a series of ids from a local cube to piggy back off of the dynamic security, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I have tried openquery, but when I try that I get an error that is not very useful

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "coop3-t3500" returned message "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 2

An error occurred while preparing the query

The query I am trying to run is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM openrowset([servername], MDX query)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it to work, it appears that because I had two analysis services project on the SSAS server, it was only connecting to the first one.